# Error : Parsing the package while installing APK

Tags: android, apk

I'm trying to install my app by running Package Installer from the email attachment in Yahoo. My phone is on version 4.1 (Jellybean), so this should work, right?

However, I get an error saying that there was a problem parsing the package despite the fact that my AndroidManifest specifies a `minSdkVersion` of 1, and my phone's is higher.

I have enabled installing `apk` from sources that aren't from the playstore on my phone. What am I missing?

Comment: What APK are you trying to install? Usually this error is displayed if the APK is corrupt or cannot be installed (required OS version is above yours)

Comment: This site is for programming questions. Software installation is offtopic.

Comment: @ilan321, I'm trying to install the apk file from the 'bin' folder in my project. My manifest specifies that the minimum version is 1.0, so I don't think that should be a problem.

Comment: @Trust I have answered to your question. It will help you

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> I get an error saying that there was a problem parsing the package.

This because your app is not compatible with your device. It might your developer set the `minSDKVersion` value to high and If your device API level is lower then `minSDKVersion` then it gives parsing package error or your developer set the maxSDKVersion to lower than your device API level.

For ex : If your device is Android 2.2 then your developer who made the APK set the `minSDKVersion` to 10 then it wont work in the Android 2.2 and will give the parsing package error or If your developer set the `maxSDKVersion` to 8 then app won't install above Android OS 2.2 and if you try to install then you will get the Parsing package error.

Comment: This can't be the problem. I have specified '<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="1" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />' in my manifest, and my phone's version is 4.1.

Comment: It might your APK has corrupted and if it is not then factory reset your device or download the APK in the internal phone memory then install it from there

Comment: My min sdk version is 10 and max is 21
all was running good until my phone upated to lollypop 5.0 and now the app crashes what should i do
The app runs fine in NEXUS 5 emulator but not on the phone

Comment: For security reasons, we can't install the application from unknown sources like mail attachment. You need to install the app from unknown sources you should enable the "Unknown Source option" in Security settings.