# Parsing the package error for Sony Tablet S

Tags: android

I have tested my app in several real devices such as `Lenovo Yoga Tablet
2-830LC 8 inch (Quad-core 1.86 GHz) Android: 5.0.1`, `Lenovo A7-30 A3300 7 inch (Quad-core 1.3 GHz Cortex-A7) Android: 4.2.2` and `Sony Tablet S 9.4 inch (Quad-core 1.3 GHz Cortex-A9) Android: 4.0.3`.

The first and second tablet showed the output but the third tablet showed **Parsing the package error**.

I have:
Compile using Android version: Use Latest Platform `(Android 6.0 (Marshmallow)
Minimum Android to target: Android 4.1 (API Level 16-Jelly Bean))`
Target Android Version: Use compile using SDK Version

I uses `armeabi-v7a`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21808188/error-parsing-the-package-while-installing-apk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sony Tablet S 9.4 inch (Quad-core 1.3 GHz Cortex-A9) Android: 4.0.3.

Your minimum Android target is 4.1

Comment: Minimum Android to target: Android 4.0 (API Level 14-Ice Cream sandwich)) is good for most systems? Or lower should be chosen?

Comment: its depends on your target user device and library that your application used