# Installing APK not working, but deploying from Android studio works

Tags: android, android-studio, package-managers

## Edit

### The APK is a signed one which have the problem, while installing directly from android studio causes no issues. (Only using the APK).

After finishing developing the app I tried to generate an APK and give to a friend for a test; He said it's not working (not installable). So I grapped the phone Motorolla with Android 6.0.1 and tried to debug the problem from the Android Monitor in Android studio and this was the error there :

> unable to parse package file android

Then i tried the same APK on the same phone i was using to test (Samsung J3 with 5.1.1 Android version) and got the following error in the logs of Android monitor:

> Class not found when unmarshalling:
>   com.android.packageinstaller.InstallFlowAnalytics

I never had this or something like it before, googled a bit and tried to find an answer on SOF found a couple of answers which none of them worked.

- disabled proGuard
- added android:extractNativeLibs="true" to manifest
- Increased/Decreased the SDK version

as I said none of these worked, any idea ?

This is my manifest and my Gradle files :

## Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my.package.myapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ice_launder"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="my.package.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="my.package.MoreLikeThisActivity" />
        <activity android:name="my.package.SearchResultActivity" />
        <activity android:name="my.package.LastResultsActivity" />
        <activity android:name="my.package.CompanyDetailsActivity" />
        <activity android:name="my.package.OnboardingActivity"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

## Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.package.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral() // jcenter() works as well because it pulls from Maven Central
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:1.2.1@aar'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0'
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21808280/3395198

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya i have no max sdk, and as i said i tried this option.

Comment: Did you generate apk using Build>Build APK option?

Comment: @Nischal i built a signed one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just build your project by Build >Build APK

while using signed apk make sure you have checked both the checkbox v1 and v2

Comment: have you activated  install from “Unknown sources.” in settings @YamenNassif

Comment: i am not sure about this :- copy your project to a different location  with a different name  and try to rebuid  it from the new location

Comment: it didn't help.

Comment: does signed apk have the same problem

Comment: The signed apk is the one who have the problem, while installing directly from android studio have no problem

Comment: just build your project by Build >Build APK

Comment: while using signed apk make sure you have checked both the checkbox v1 and v2

Comment: building the apk made it work, any idea how to fix the signed one ? And please update your answer to accept it

Comment: while generating signed apk enable the proGuard

Answer (score 1):

If your are generating signed apk, you need to check both signature versions:
V1(Jar Signature) and V2(Full Apk Signature), so that your apk will run in all devices with api level as you have defined in your build.gradle file.

You can refer to this:
 https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/v2.html#verification

> In Android 7.0, APKs can be verified according to the APK Signature
>   Scheme v2 (v2 scheme) or JAR signing (v1 scheme). Older platforms
>   ignore v2 signatures and only verify v1 signatures.

Answer (score 0):

Clean project, invalidate cache and restart worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Make Project, after the the build is done you can find the file in

...AndroidStudioProjects\AppName\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk

this file should install *(worked for me)*.

Make Project icon is located here:
[this is where the icon is on Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baqre.png)